# PHP, echo COOKIE array value

Tags: php, cookies, echo, setcookie

Its not echoing the `COOKIE` instead shows an error.

> Error:Undefined index: pref[fontSize]

```
setcookie('pref[fontSize]',25);
setcookie('pref[favCategory]','news');
setcookie('pref[screenWidth]',1024);

echo $_COOKIE['pref[fontSize]'];
```

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($_COOKIE);` ?

Comment: it will be available on the next request

Comment: @BeatAlex `array(2) { ["pref"]=> array(3) { ["fontSize"]=> string(2) "25" ["favCategory"]=> string(4) "news" ["screenWidth"]=> string(2) "25" } ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "5mr3d4tt3uab6kdkal0blt1qt2" } `

Comment: OK so it is setting then! Like the others have said you need to wait until the next request :)

Comment: @Ghost what do you mean by _next request_.

Comment: @CoDINGinDARK you can't get the values outright of assignment, it'll be accessible after that request. since the values are already set, just treat it as you would normally treat an array

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [setCookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), suggests that `$_COOKIE` will not hold vals from `setCookie`, till after the cookie has been set client side (e.g. next request, because the user might have their browser configured to not save cookies).

Answer (score 0):

you should go with this

```
echo $_COOKIE['pref']['fontSize'];
```